# TestNG Custom Exception to be throw at the time of Excection TimeOut

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to catch `ThreadTimeOut` Exception but I am not able to catch that Exception My code look like but I am getting error at catch (`ThreadTimeOutException t`) any help will be appreciated

```
@Test(timeOut=2000)
public void timoutCheck() throws Exception {
    try {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("sdfsdsdfsdfsdfsdf");
        }
    }

    catch (Error e) {
        // System.out.println(message+
        // "(Java Exception: "+e.getMessage()+")");
        throw new Exception("(Java Exception: " + e.getMessage() + ")");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // System.out.println(message+
        // "(Java Exception: "+e.getMessage()+")");
        throw new Exception("(Java Exception: " + e.getMessage() + ")");

    } catch (ThreadTimeoutException t) {
        System.out.println("timeouttttt----->");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code won't compile, since you are catching a specific exception after catching all exceptions in the first catch block.  Move your catch of ThreadTimeOutException before catching Exceptions generically to get rid of the error.

Comment: I moved the catch block at the very first position still i am facing the same issue :(

Comment: This is because your code in the try block cannot throw this exception.  TestNG executor throws it and terminates your test.

Comment: So is it possible to handle this exception ??

Comment: That would depend upon what do u need it for - the fact that you put a timeout means that you want your test to fail if it exceeds the timeout.  TestNG does it by throwing the exception.  You do have access to the exception via the result object - which you can get in @AfterMethod or by implementing a listener, based on need